# How to retain Field Name / Alias on Export of Table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, table, fields-attributes

Is there a way I can modify the Field Name or to make him keep the Alias when a table is exported?

Or is there a way to keep the Alias instead of the Field Name, when exporting for example to .dbf ?

I want to be able to do this in ArcMap.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you use the ArcToolbox Tool "Table to Table" you can add, rename, or delete output fields using the Field Map Parameter. With arcpy you can use the tool and build your own field map. That field map can use the aliasName property of the field object (have a look at the **[FieldMappings example 2](http://resources.arcgis.com/de/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000078000000)**.

With **ArcGIS 10.1** you are able to rename the field name in ArcCatalog (table properties), if your data source is a FileGeodatabase.

Answer (score 4):

The most reliable way to do this in ArcMap is to use the **[Table to Excel (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000054000000)** tool, making sure the *Use field alias as column header* checkbox is checked:

> How column names in the output are determined.
>
> - NAME —Column headers will be set using the input's field names. This is the default.
> - ALIAS —Column headers will be set using the input's field aliases.

Comment: I'm finding that the alias values are ignored, and instead the field name is used. Have you had better luck? I'm using 10.2

Comment: also in 10.4 , Using fields allias as column header in "Table to Excel" does not works.

Comment: also in 10.6, "Table to Excel" with alias checked but it's ignored...

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this to work in 10.6, the key was to save the alias field in ArcCatalog  (not ArcMap).

Which is what I think the poorly written note means to say:
Column headers will be set using the input geodatabase table's field aliases. If the input is a layer in a map, the value set on the layer's field alias is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

There is 65535 record limit for the table to XLS tool. We need the option to use aliases in a csv export.